# Do I need to put blood in a vacuum sealed bag to cook it sous vide in this type of appliance?

Tags: equipment, sous-vide, pasteurization

If I used this type of appliance...
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01N1PQTIV/
... to pasteurise blood at 60°C for 45 minutes (as per these instructions: https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/blood-sauce), would I have to put the blood in a vacuum sealed bag or could I just pour it directly into that pot?

If doing the latter is possible as well, how would it affect the blood's consistency and taste by comparison to cooking it in a bag?

[image]

Comment: Yep, use vacuum (sealable) bags

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the photos in the webshop it's pretty clear to me that you're still supposed to bag whatever food goes in it. It will make clean up of the machine easier and you don't want blood residues on it for your next batch of food.

Perhaps you don't need to vacuum seal it, just squeeze out as much air as possible with the [vacuum displacement method](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25579/is-a-vacuum-strictly-necessary-for-sous-vide-cooking/79078#79078) and trap the edge of the bag between the pot and the lid.

Comment: You can also use kind of a cheater's vacuum seal, which is just a ziploc-type bag with as much of the air as possible squeezed out. If you're concerned about leaks, you can double bag.

Comment: yeah, I was talking about the first one which I usually do since I don't own a vacuum sealer. I'll include in the answer. For low temperatures and short times the risk of leaks is quite small.

Comment: @Luciano I was wondering how a vacuum sealer would work if you've a fluid in the bag. There's a risk of it sucking up some of that too instead of just air, isn't there?

Lying in bed this morning I suddenly also remembered how my grandmother creates a vacuum when she bags food for freezing. She just sucks the air out with her mouth. ^^ Though that wouldn't be very hygienic if you also cooked for others.

Comment: @BloodyCurious Some sealers can handle fluids; not all models do.